Create a copy of fedora boot and filesystem partition and create a new grub instance for it
After a partly successful dual boot with Fedora 40 and Windows 10. I had to delete my blocked Windows boot from my SDD. I removed the EFI entry and the two Windows specific partitions.
Now I would like to install Windows again but give my Linux installation more space on the disk (from 100 to 300 GB) but this is sadly not so easy because both of my Linux partitions (boot & file system) are at the physical end of the SSD. So I have to move my both Linux partitions to the beginning of my SSD.
What I want to achieve is to create a copy of the boot partition and copy the content of the file system to a bigger partition. Now I don't want to make updates to my existing grub bootloader that was installed with Fedora on the EFI partition. I want to create a new grub bootloader that will be available as a separate UEFI boot entry and that will boot into the copy of the Fedora system. Only when I'm completely sure that my new setup works, I want to delete the old partitions, so in case when I make a mistake I can still boot into the original Fedora installation.
The new setup has to support secure boot with UEFI and I would like that everything can be done without using a live OS.
This is my idea of how to make this process the most secure, but if anyone has a better idea, I'm open for new ideas.

Only one ESP (EFI System Partition) per drive and only one is needed even with multiple drives. Also ESPs are OS agnostic and different bootloaders can and should be in the same ESP. Now knowing how it works you may want to reconsider your plan. Dual-booting Linux and Windows with modern systems should be trivial.

I think you misunderstood me there. I only want one ESP on my drive. But it should include the fedora (grub) bootloader and also the plain grub bootloader. This is the main idea of dual booting. I just want to have a backup on my laptop that I can use in cause something goes wrong.

There's no "plain grub"... GRUB is always installed by and part of an OS.
